# Solve differential equations $y'=\frac{y}{2y\ln y+x}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Solve differential equation $$y'=\frac{y}{2y\ln y+x}$$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9201), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 2):

$y'=\frac{y}{2y\ln y+x}$

$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{y}{2y\ln y+x}$

$\frac{dx}{dy}=\frac{2y\ln y+x}{y}$

$x'=\frac{2y\ln y+x}{y}$

$x'=2\ln y+\frac{x}{y}$

$x'-\frac{x}{y}=2\ln y$

$\frac{x'}{y}-\frac{x}{y^2}=\frac{2\ln y}{y}$

$D_y\left[\frac{x}{y}\right]=\frac{2\ln y}{y}$

$\int D_y\left[\frac{x}{y}\right]dy=\int \frac{2\ln y}{y}dy$

$\frac{x}{y}=\left(\ln y\right)^2+c$

$x=y\left(\ln y\right)^2+Cy$